# How do I resolve "IndexError: tuple index out of range"?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to do a time series plot forecast in transformer.
The input size is (None, 30).
However, an error occurs here.

```
x = layers.MultiHeadAttention(
      5 key_dim=1, num_heads=1, dropout=dropout
----> 6 )(inputs, inputs)
      7 x = layers.Dropout(dropout)(x)
      8 x = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(x)
```

An error occurs here.
IndexError: tuple index out of range

```
def transformer_encoder(inputs, head_size, num_heads, ff_dim, dropout=0):
    # Attention and Normalization
    print(inputs.shape)
    x = layers.MultiHeadAttention(
        key_dim=head_size, num_heads=num_heads, dropout=dropout
    )(inputs, inputs)
    x = layers.Dropout(dropout)(x)
    x = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(x)
    res = x + inputs
​
    # Feed Forward Part
    x = layers.Conv1D(filters=ff_dim, kernel_size=1, activation="relu")(res)
    x = layers.Dropout(dropout)(x)
    x = layers.Conv1D(filters=inputs.shape[-1], kernel_size=1)(x)
    x = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(x)
    return x + res
```

```
def build_model(
    input_shape,
    head_size,
    num_heads,
    ff_dim,
    num_transformer_blocks,
    mlp_units,
    dropout=0,
    mlp_dropout=0,
):
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = inputs
    for _ in range(num_transformer_blocks):
        x = transformer_encoder(x, head_size, num_heads, ff_dim, dropout)

    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(data_format="channels_first")(x)
    for dim in mlp_units:
        x = layers.Dense(dim, activation="relu")(x)
        x = layers.Dropout(mlp_dropout)(x)
    outputs = layers.Dense(n_classes)(x)
    return keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
input_shape = X_train.shape[1:]
model_mlp = build_model(
    input_shape,
    head_size=256,
    num_heads=1,
    ff_dim=1,
    num_transformer_blocks=4,
    mlp_units=[128],
    mlp_dropout=0.4,
    dropout=0.25,
)

model_mlp.compile(optimizer = adam, loss = root_mean_squared_error)
model_mlp.summary()
```

I am trying to do a time series plot forecast in transformer.
The input size is (None, 30).
However, an error occurs here.

Comment: input shape should be (None, 30, 1). Make `X_train = tf.expand_dims(X_train, -1)`

Comment: Thank you. ButI got this error.　ValueError: Input 0 of layer global_average_pooling1d_2 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=7. Full shape received: (None, 30, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1).

Comment: x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(data_format="channels_first")(x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following changes,

```
X_train = tf.expand_dims(X_train, -1) #change your input
input_shape = X_train.shape[1:] #input shape should change to (30,1)
model_mlp = build_model(
    input_shape,
    head_size=256,
    num_heads=1,
    ff_dim=1,
    num_transformer_blocks=4,
    mlp_units=[128],
    mlp_dropout=0.4,
    dropout=0.25,
)

model_mlp.compile(optimizer = adam, loss = root_mean_squared_error)
model_mlp.summary()
```

then check,

```
model_mlp(X_train)
```